# formula from 2s complement to decimal please

Tags: math-software, combinatorial-designs

Hi what is the formula for an $n$ bit twos complement to decimal..
for example
from $ n$ bit unsigned to decimal the formula is..  $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i 2^i$

from signed magnitude to decimal is $(-1)^{a_{n-1}}$ $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a_i 2^i$

i need from twos complement to decimal formula please  these above are correct

Answer (score 1):

If the number is positive, the lead bit is zero and your unsigned expression applies.  If the number is negative, treat the number as positive and apply your unsigned expression, getting a value of $m$.  Then the answer is $m-2^n$.  You can combine them into $\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} a_i 2^i\right)-a_{n-1}2^{n-1}$